# How can I execute public method from javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with access to the function defined in external file, please give a piece of advice how can I fix following.

Page code:

```
  var be = null;
    $(document)
      .ready(function() {
        be = $("#article-content")
          .bootstrapeditor({
            //
          });

        // how can I call public method wizardWorkedOut from 
        // https://jsfiddle.net/f0rza/572q21fj/ ?
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0rza/jhotm90r/

External script:

```
! function($) {

  var BootstrapEditor = function(element, options) {

    this.canDemolishEditor = true;

  };

  BootstrapEditor.prototype.wizardWorkedOut = function() {
    this.wizardWorkedOut();
  };

  BootstrapEditor.prototype = {
    constructor: BootstrapEditor,

    wizardWorkedOut: function() {
      console.log('bootstrap-editor instance: wizardWorkedOut');
      this.canDemolishEditor = true;
    }
  };

  $.fn.bootstrapeditor = function(option, val) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data("bootstrapeditor"),
        options = typeof option === "object" && option;
      if (!data) {
        $this.data("bootstrapeditor",
          (data = new BootstrapEditor(this, $.extend({}, 
                                      $.fn.bootstrapeditor.defaults, options))));
      }
      if (typeof option === "string") data[option](val);
    });
  };

  $.fn.bootstrapeditor.defaults = {
    onRender: function(date) {
      return "";
    }
  };
  $.fn.bootstrapeditor.Constructor = BootstrapEditor;

}(window.jQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0rza/572q21fj/

Comment: You have to create an instance of `BootstrapEditor`, then you can call its methods e.g. `wizardWorkedOut`

Comment: Even after object is initialized I get an error: http://take.ms/re9FU

Answer (score 0):

You can access by creating an instance of BootstrapEditor, as shown below.

```
 //Creating an instance of bootstrapeditor
 var instance = new be.__proto__.bootstrapeditor.Constructor()
 //Access the methods in the prototype
 instance.wizardWorkedOut()
```